# Keras model not learning and predicting only one class out of three classes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

New to the field of deep learning and currently working on [this](https://www.drivendata.org/competitions/57/nepal-earthquake/page/136/#features_list) competition for predicting the earthquake damage to buildings.

The model I created starts at an accuracy of .56 but remains at this for any number of epochs i let it run. When finished, the model only predicts one of the three classes (which I one hot encoded into a dataframe with three columns). **Changing the number of layers, optimizers, data preparation, dropout** wont change anything. Even trying to overfit my model with the over-parameterization of the neural network will still have the same accuracy and a **non-learning model**.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, input_dim = 85, activation = "relu"))
keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = "relu"))
keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = "relu"))
keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = "relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation = "softmax"))

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

model.compile(optimizer = adam,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(traindata, trainlabels,
                    epochs = 5,
                    validation_split = 0.2,
                    verbose = 1,)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing visually wrong with your model, but it may be too haevy to learn any useful features.

1. Try normalizing your input with https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html
2. Start with only 2 layers, and a few numbers of neurons.
3. Increase `batch_size` and try learning_rate scheduling.
4. Observe the validation_accuracy, stop when it starts to overfit.

Finally, for a 3-class classification, 56% accuracy is better than baseline, remmeber it's a competition so the data is not dummy playground data which you can expect to get a 90% accuracy with an MLP in the first try.

Finally, try hyperparameter optimization with `tuner`.